# Why my laptop is hard to turn on?

Tags: linux, boot, laptop, battery

My laptop is Acer Aspire 4738Z with 4GB RAM, but without battery, so I must plug the laptop in my room.

In this video at link, my laptop is hard to turn on sometimes, every time I press the power button, my indicator lamp is turned on at seconds, but the laptop goes turned off quickly. Sometime, I have seen the boot screen from vendor and operating system (LMDE) but after that, it's turned off quickly.

This is my link of the laptop condition when I tried to turned it on.
⬇️⬇️⬇️

https://drive.google.com/file/d/12EBPpiTXfEbSvWSUuX59LXr1wIlyln5p/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: We don't like clicking links to random files in shared drives. You can upload videos to video sites and set them private and share the link. Based on what you've written, your laptop hardware is faulty/failing. Besides updating the BIOS and all drivers, you should probably take your laptop to a competent computer technician.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing you or anyone else can do. The firmware of your laptop, for some reason, decides to not boot. Since you can't modify that firmware, you can do essentially nothing.

Comment: Yes, but luckily, my laptop can boot in many time

Comment: Any answers maybe?

Comment: that is an answer. You can't do anything about it, it is the firmware. Bad luck!

Comment: Marcus are you suggesting perhaps the firmware is detecting a fault and refusing to boot? Firmware can be changed, flashed, updated, etc. The firmware itself will not just decide not to boot without reason.

Comment: no, @music2myear. I'm suggesting that laptop firmware does whatever it does; it's usually not the greatest piece of software ever written, and honestly, there's far too many things that could cause this, from aged sensors over bad contacts to integer overflows to plain old programming mistakes, that I'm not willing to even speculate what it is that caused the firmware to behave that way.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Don't forget the capacitors. And many other components, of course. This is an entry-level laptop from 2010 (Pentium 6100 + Intel GMA + 2GB originally) that if not properly cleaned and the thermal paste replaced will overheat for sure thus potentially affecting any component. I had an high-end laptop (about USD 2500 in 2014) that failed completely - no POST, all 3 LEDs flashing - last year.